# Trouble Using the escape character '{'

Tags: java, arraylist, escaping

In my book it asks me to design a simple program that converts a .java file using End of line brace style to a new .java file with new line brace style. I need to find which lines end with a '{'. I read that I need to use two backlashes in front of the '{' instead of just { since it is one of the escape characters in java.

Here's what I have:

```
public class BraceConverter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File sourceFile = new File(args[0]);
    File newFile = new File(args[1]);

    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Error: 2 arguments are required for the program to be executed");
    }
    else if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        System.err.println("Error: source file " + args[0] + " does not exist.");
    }
    else {
        ArrayList<String> newProgramLines = new ArrayList<>();
        int i = 0;
        try(Scanner input = new Scanner(sourceFile);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(newFile)) {
            while(input.hasNext()) {
                newProgramLines.add(input.nextLine());
                if (newProgramLines.get(i).endsWith("\\{")) {
                        newProgramLines.set(i, newProgramLines.get(i).replaceAll("{", ""));
                        newProgramLines.add("{");
                        i++;
                }
                i++;
            }

            for(String x: newProgramLines) {
                output.println(x);
            }
        }

    }

  }     

}
```

However the program is not working and when I stepped through it with the debugger, the if statement:

```
if (newProgramLines.get(i).endsWith("\\{")) <---I actually have 2 backslashes in my code not sure why it can only show one backslash on here
```

always evaluated to false even when the array at the specific index ends with a `{`.

If instead of putting 2 backslashes followed by a `{` I put ";" into the method, it evaluates to true with no problem. Why is it then that using 2 backslashes followed by a `{` is evaluating to false and how can I fix this to return true when the last character in the line is a '{'.

Comment: No, you don't have to escape `{` inside a `String` . So `if (newProgramLines.get(i).endsWith("{"))` is fine .

Comment: You could just use [`replace("{","")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead of [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). You don't need regular expressions for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. For  `endsWith(String suffix)` the suffix is a basic `String` no need to espace:

   ```
   if (newProgramLines.get(i).endsWith("{")) {
   ```

---

2. For `replaceAll(String regex, String repl)` there is a `regex` so here you need to escape with a `\` (Java warning you as a *dangling metacharacter*), and in Java you need to escpace the backslash, so need 2

   ```
   newProgramLines.set(i, newProgramLines.get(i).replaceAll("{", ""));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
.endsWith("\\{")
```

Will only return true for strings that end with

```
\{
```

The backslash IS an escape character, but by using double backslashes you're escaping the backslash. The '{' does not need to be escaped.

Using only

```
.endsWith("{")
```

Should work just fine